# Fabricjs let me rotate and edit only the first clicked image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fabricjs

I programmed a code that implements canvas, caman and fabricjs. This is supposed to rotate, edit colors and save the image when I click on a button. It works fine, but just with the first clicked image. When I click on the button again to show another image for edition, the screen shows the image but do not let me edit it. In other words, if I click on the image, then the first image clicked shows again for edition. I call the command alert to see which path the image was returning, and it is returning correctly.

Here is my code:

```
TScript::create("
    temp_img_id = '{$id}';
    temp_img = '{$filename->path_filename}';

    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imgFilePreview');
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

    canvas.setHeight(500);
    canvas.setWidth(500);

    fabric.Image.fromURL(temp_img, function(objects){
        var obj = objects.scale(0.75);
        obj.scaleToHeight(350);
        obj.scaleToWidth(350);
        canvas.centerObject(obj);
        canvas.add(obj);

        $('.canvas-container').css({
            'width': '900px',
            'height': '900px',
            'position': 'relative',
            'user-select': 'none'
        });
        $('#canvas').css({
            'border': '1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204)',
            'width': '500px',
            'height': '500px',
            'left': '0px',
            'top': '0px', 
            'touch-action': 'manipulation',
            'user-select': 'none'
        });
        $('.upper-canvas').css({
            'border': '1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204)',
            'width': '500px',
            'height': '500px',
            'left': '0px',
            'top': '0px',
            'touch-action': 'manipulation',
            'user-select': 'none',
            'cursor': 'default'
        });

        $('#canvas').attr({'width': '500', 'height': '500'});
        $('.upper-canvas').attr({'width': '500', 'height': '500'});
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
");
```

I run this code to perform the image edition. I use the adianti framework developed by Pablo Dall'Oglio. I just check if the image paths was returning with the correct contents. I do not know how can I solve this. I searched for solutions, but without success.